# include style sheets in all pages asp vbscript

Tags: css, asp-classic, vbscript, include

How can I include pages, style sheets, or links to them, automatically into my ASP VBscript pages? I read something about 'global' pages, but I am unsure what they mean and how it is that I can accomplish such a thing. I'm sure this is an easy question, but it's of great help to me as I've been writing VBscript for 2 days now! I'm not exactly an expert on HTML in general either, but I feel I have a reasonably good grasp of things. I would appreciate a good detailed example of how a 'global' page plays with my other ASP pages.

I'm setting up my first site...a management site for the main site I intend to build afterward.  I want to get all my ducks in a row before moving forward with the public site.  Can someone please give me some detailed information on how to include these pages/links automatically (page includes(header/footer), style sheets, etc) globally throughout my site without the need of using `<!--#include file....` on each page I make, because that is kind of a pain and I'm sure there is an easier way. If there is, I know you can help! Thanks in advance, I look forward to hearing what options/possibilities are available.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular why you choose to base a new site (and your own personal leanings) on a obsolete technology? ASP Classic went out of fashion 10+ years ago and is unsupported (at least it doesn't develop any more). You should probabaly look into ASP.NET if you want to do greenfield development... :-)

Comment: I currently work on old webpages that are written using asp vbscript, so in order to get much more familiar with the language and usage i decided to make my site as such.  I know classic asp is outdated... i am up to date with the .Net framework, so im not as concerned with learning asp.net as i already write c# and know a large amount of classes/methods.  I suppose what im getting at is that, this is a learning experience.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure of your skilllevel so if you were entering the programmingprofession I would have suggested you start somewhere else... as long as you know what you are doing that's OK I guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using ASP Classic you may find some method for handling masterpage like functionality but it is, to the best of my knowledge, not suppoerted as such by the framework.

**[Edit] Given the edit of the original question the method first demonstrated is not so interesting, hence I suggest an alternative method too.**

You could make a general ASP-page which serves all traffic to the site. A queryparameter then specifies which subpage should be displayed. Subpages are made as seperate ASP-pages which are executed by the general/master page or by another subpage. A very crude example of this could look like this:

```
<%
url = Request.QueryString("url") & ""
if url = "/" or url = "" then
  subpage = "home.asp"
else
  subpage = url & ".asp"
end if
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Header for all pages</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <% Server.Execute(subpage) %>

</body>
</html>
```

The site should then be addressed in this fashion:

```
www.domain.com/default.asp?url=/contact
```

which would load the contact.asp subpage into the masterpage or:

```
www.domain.com/default.asp?url=/user/1234/profile
```

to load a user's profilepage (displayed by the profile.asp in the folder user/1234). This last example raises some issues because then every user has to have a folder containing all the asp-files (which is far from optimal) so you might want to employ some interpretation of the url queryparameter to redirect input in a more intelligent way.

Another issue is the fact that subpages are ASP-pages themselves which means someone could reference them directly. This calls for some action to protect those subpages from direct reference. It can be done but this would probably mean including some code => back to square one!

Another disadvantages of this approach is that subpages are rendered in their own context and hence can't access functionality and data from the calling page's context. This means that global data has to be shared in some other way (session, application, database or some other way). Data can't be passed to the subpage either (and no, Server.Execute doesn't allow query-parameters).

**The include-way**

Personally I think you get the most flexibility by using header/footer includes as demonstrated in my original post and shown below.

One way is to put your general stuff in includes and then includes those bits on each ASP-page. E.g.:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/includes/header.asp" -->

content goes here

<!-- #include virtual="/includes/footer.asp" -->
```

And your header.asp could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Header for all pages</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

and footer.asp like so:

```
</body>
</html>
```

This strategy has some disadvantages. The header is fairly static which could present some problems with SEO; For one the title should fit the pagecontent which is hard to accomplish when the include contains the header-markup. This could be facilitated by some global variables that are set prior to the include-section i.e.:

```
<%
title = "Title for this page's content"
%> 
<!-- #include virtual="/includes/header.asp" -->

content goes here

<!-- #include virtual="/includes/footer.asp" -->
```

and then in the header like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%=title%></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

but that already begins to "smell" a little because you set up some expectations for the including page inside the include-file. At least you have to be very disciplined when constructing your pages.

Comment: Thanks for the post, lots of good info here that i didnt know.  Im gonna have to read and research what you mentioned here, but im sure what i needed is here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is Master Page, not Global Page, that may be why you're having a hard time finding what you're looking for on Google. Basically consider a master page a template. You create a master page, then load other pages into it. There are content place holders that you put in the master then populate on your other pages.

So a very basic example would look something like this.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="general.master.vb" Inherits="master1_general"%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css?v2"/>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your individual pages would look like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/master/general.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="base.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" title="Opportunities" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

//any additional head stuff specific to this page goes here.

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server" >

//your body mark up goes here.
</asp:Content>
```

Notice how the Master page is actually a web page. Then it has place holders in certain spots. In this one there is a place holder in the head and one in the body. Then on individual pages I identify which master page to use and what data (if any) goes in the place holders. I always include a placeholder in the head so I can load js or resources that specific pages need on that page only.

Then the individual pages are just the content that goes in the placeholders.

Comment: >.< too early for me to be here... I'll leave it for now just in case the question was tagged wrong.

Comment: It was tagged correctly, but i appreciate you taking the time to answer.  Once i start writing some asp.net pages im sure it will help.  Thanks